# A new version of a package introduced unexpected behavior - how to discover the source of the issue?

Tags: org-mode, debugging, package

### My issue

There is a small behavior in org-mode that I've grown accustomed to: if there are multiple headlines of the same level (e.g. 3 stars) and they are all folded (i.e. their contents are not visible) and you navigate to the end of some headline (`C-e`) and then press enter (`RET`), the old behavior was to insert an empty line between the headlines, make it visible and put the cursor there. However, some time ago the behavior changed and what happens now is that after pressing `RET`, a new blank line is also inserted at the end of the headline, but it is not immediately visible as a new blank line (i.e. it remains folded under the headline) and the only way to discover that something has changed in the buffer is look at the line numbers on the left and see that 1 more line has been added.

### General question

What is the best way to debug a case like this? I believe the issue appeared around the time I've updated to org-mode version 9.5. For now, my starting point is reading org-mode change logs and looking for changes related to keywords such as 'indentation', 'headlines', etc. Is there a better way to approach this?

Of course, if anybody is familiar with the exact change I'm talking about, I would appreciate a direct help - e.g. what variable to change, etc

Comment: Before you do anything else, you should read the `etc/ORG_NEWS` file (just the section(s) between your old version and 9.5): you might get lucky and find the change documented. Otherwise, if you can figure out which version did *not* exhibit the problem, then you can bisect the commits between that version and 9.5 and figure out the culprit PDQ. You will need some knowledge of `git`, you'll need to clone the Org mode git repository (if you haven't already), and you'll need an example file for testing. Then read the manual page for `git-bisect` and have at it.